# Multi resolution

Tags: c#, winforms

How To make user Control run on multiple resolution 
it run will on resolution 1366 X 768  but when I try to run it on 800 X 600 
part of it did not appear , wheteherI docked it on the main form

Comment: Can you specify what you are trying to accomplish through the user control also.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at

[How do I resize controls on a form to fit different resolutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638685/how-do-i-resize-controls-on-a-form-to-fit-different-resolutions)

Answer (score 0):

You have to distinguish between Size of your Control and the used dpi settings.

The size part is quite easy. Just use the `Anchor` and `Docking` properties of your user control and set also these properties of all child controls within your user control.

If your layout is more complex you can use the `TableLayoutPanel`. And don't forget the usage of `MinimumSize` and maybe `MaximumSize`.

About taking care with different dpi Settings i didn't make any further investigations. So maybe someone else knows how you can accomplish this problem within .Net